# Can't find symbol even though class is in the same folder

Tags: java

I have looked at all the other stuff, mine is a compatibility issue I think, or PATH maybe. I have a bunch of classes I've been using since about 2008 and now the java command and the javac command can't find the classes even though they are in the same directory/folder. I have `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin` in the Path variable, but nothing in the `Classpath`. I normally have the compiled classes in the same folder with the java I'm compiling. I've been doing the same thing for 5 years! I have recompiled the lowest level class which is called `WotifCat01`. The compiler comes back with

WotifCat00.java:27:cannot find symbol

Symbol : WotifCat01

```
import java.io.*;

/** Find/replace program **/

class WotifCat00 
{ 
    private static int cnt; 

    private static String[][] filnamStrg={ {"Data/reftfile.txt","Data/AccumData/allreftfile.txt","","",""}, 
                                           {"Data/reft1file.txt","Data/AccumData/allreft1file.txt","","",""},
                                           {"Data/reft2file.txt","Data/AccumData/allreft2file.txt","","",""},
                                           {"Data/reft3file.txt","Data/AccumData/allreft3file.txt","","",""}, 
                                           {"Data/reft4file.txt","Data/AccumData/allreft4file.txt","","",""},
                                           {"Data/work1file.txt","Data/AccumData/alltextsrc.txt","","",""},
                                           {"","","","",""}  };

    private static String[] args1={"","","","",""}; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        while (filnamStrg[cnt][0] != "") {  

            args1[0] = filnamStrg[cnt][0];                         
            args1[1] = filnamStrg[cnt][1];

            WotifCat01 wotifCat01 = new WotifCat01();   
            wotifCat01.main(args1); 

            cnt++;     
        }     
    }
}
```

I've used this setup for a while and it worked fine on my laptop till now with Windows 7. I suspect something I've installed has overwritten something. This has to be really simple but I can't see it. I've removed jdk1.7.0_25 back to 1.6 but no change.

I backed up the classpath and deleted it. Now works fine. It contained IBM DB2 paths. DB2 I had installed in 2011 so discounted it, but it did have java paths in it so it must have overrode the path. I am not sure how DB2 managed to do so 2 years after install, I may have inadvertently activated something. Thanks for your input.
Neil Mc

Comment: How come you have no import for class 'wotifCat01'? Is it in the same file? Are you developing with eclipse? Does it underline it?

Comment: @Harry: he said, that the classes in the same Folder, so no import ir needed

Comment: @user3111556: are you able to compile any other java files? write a minimal java file, compile and run it, is it ok?  then try to compile  wotifCat01.java first, then  wotifCat00.

Comment: Hi Rami, I can compile WotifCat01 as it doesn't have any references apart from import java.io.*; When I say the classpath has nothing in it it has nothing to do with the jdk, what sequence does java look thru the current directory and classpath? What does it look for is it possible that something else in the classpath is being found first?

Comment: take a look here: http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-compile-and-launch-java-code-from-command-line/

Comment: why not using eclipse IDE?